# Reledmac: sidenotes between pstarts

Tags: reledmac

I'm wondering whether there is a way to put a sidenote between two paragraphs, this way:

```
\pstart blablabla \pend

blabla \ledrightnote(or whatever){blablabla}

\pstart blablabla \pend
```

I have tried both \ledrightnote and the traditional \marginpar. The former gives me back an error, the latter has no effect.

Comment: have you tried the `marginnote`-package?

Comment: Yes, no effect at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\ledrightnote` etc is not supposed to work in unnumbered text.
Both `\marginpar{}` and `\marginnote{}` do work together with `reledmac` though:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{book}

\usepackage[a5paper,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[series={A},noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}

\beginnumbering
\pstart blablabla \pend

blabla \marginpar{par} bla

blabla \marginnote{note} bla

\pstart blablabla \pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

If you are still having troubles, you should try to build a MNWE to find out what else in your code might be in the way for the marginnotes to work.
(Eg. margin-setting outside of the printing area is a possible culprit.)

Comment: yes, it was a margin-setting problem. Now I have to understand how to move a bit left the sidenote...